# Local users can see other files but can't edit them, how to make them edit too?

Tags: file-sharing

I created a folder with group permission so I and my two other siblings can access this shared folder. They can delete files or add to it but the problem lies when I save for example, a writer document from my brother(we'll call him James).

As "Arkad"(my username), I can see his file but if I were to do edits, it doesn't allow me. Instead, I have to go the account of james, go to permission and change it from james to "compartido"(my name for the shared group) before I can do any real time changes.

How can I make it so that anyone in the group can do edits to files while simultaneously showing up in each other's users without having to manually assign the files in the folder to the "compartido" group?

Comment: I may be wrong, but you have to manually mark each file as "compartido" for each user to see them.

Answer (score 2):

Modify folder attributes to 2770

```
sudo chmod 2770 folder
```

Modify folder ownership to user james and group compartido

```
sudo chown james:compartido folder
```

This will create files in folder with read/ rights for user who creates file and read / write rights for group compartido.

Comment: Awesome, I would just do the same for the other users right?

Comment: You have to do this commands only once. Owner james is not relevant, group compartido is. You have to only add users to group compartido and that is all.

Comment: Okay let me try it after work and get back to you!

Comment: I'm having some difficulty doing this in the terminal, it says that chmod cannot access my folder name:no such file or directory? If the name of the folder were to be super folder shouldn't the command be:
 
>    sudo chmod 2770 super folder ?

Comment: No just `sudo chmod 2770 super`. Where did you create this folder ? You can open terminal on folder path you want to change by opening parent folder of folder super and than right click on folder super and select "Open in terminal". Terminal will open and enter command `cd ..` to set path to parent folder of folder super. In parent folder of folder super type commands`sudo chmod 2770 super` and `sudo chown james:compartido super`. You can check the current path in terminal by command `pwd`.

Comment: I still am not getting the right access. Here is a link that takes you to a screenshot of what I am talking about:

https://postimg.org/image/gfq12jcvj/